# SQL - Returning Products that contain multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to query what products contain 3 different parts. Must contain all 3 parts and return just the product name. If product 1 has part a, b, and c , return "Product 1"

This is how my data is structured:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsyHW.png)
It is an Oracle database.

I appreciate any help!
I could not find an answer so please direct me if this already been answered.
Thank you!

Select Product from Table
where part like 'a and b and c'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish it with this query:

```
SELECT Product
FROM your_table_name
WHERE Part IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
GROUP BY Product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Part) = 3;
```

This will return just the product value for columns where the product value has all those parts mentioned. In the filtering condition, `WHERE Part IN ('a', 'b', 'c')` you are selecting all rows that have those values. In the next line, `GROUP BY Product` you're combining rows that have the same product name into a single group. This is the helpful for the next line, `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Part) = 3;` where you are filtering the grouped results and only grabbing the records that have exactly 3 distinct different parts - in this case a, b, and c.

Comment: How could exclude products that contain a certain part on top of this? I would like to add a "but does not include part E"